# can this be done in one line in python?

Tags: python

I feel this can be done in one line, but I cannot find a way to do.

```
# final_list is what I want as an output
final_list = []

for x in some_list:
   # y is a dictionary
   y = x.get_some_dict()

   # Want to add a new key/value pair to y, which comes from x
   y.update({"new_key": x.property_in_x})
   # append y to the output list
   final_list.append(y)

return final_list
```

Comment: I think the better question is why are you going to take perfectly good code and cram it into one, probably unreadable, line.

Comment: It would be tricky to do this in one line because of the `dict.update`, and as hinted above probably much less readable

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking one liners make for better code. This code is perfectly fine, and has no good reason to be cram into one line.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend collapsing this into a one line list comprehension. It can be done, but it's bad style. List comprehensions shouldn't have side effects (i.e. calling `update`).

You could get replace the explicit list appending with a generator. That wouldn't be a bad idea. And `d[k] = v` is simpler than `d.update({k: v})`.

```
def final_list(some_list):
    for x in some_list:
        y = x.get_some_dict()
        y["new_key"] = x.property_in_x
        yield y
```

Comment: Upvoted because you gave the OP the "correct answer". _His code shouldn't be compressed into one line_.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the equivalent *list comprehension* expression along with for loop as:

```
final_list = [x.get_some_dict() for x in some_list]
for dict_item, base_item in zip(final_list, some_list):
    dict_item["new_key"] = base_item.property_in_x
```

Comment: Equivalent except that the result is a list full of `None`s

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am feeling really stupid for missing that. Big SORRY! Updated it

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend damping it into a one liner, which will (probably) be messy and unreadable. Also, the `update` makes a problem with the one liner solution.

But, In my opinion, this can be simplified, to be clearer:
(Shortened, but not to an unreadable one liner)

```py
for x in some_list:
    x.get_some_dict().update({"new_key": x.property_in_x})
final_list = [y.get_some_dict() for y in some_list]
```

Comment: What if `x.get_some_dict()` returns new object of `dict` type each time it is called?

Comment: @anonymous Good point. But if it did, it should have been mentioned

Comment: My opinion is the opposite of that. If it does, then it should be mentioned. while creating a function like `x.get_some_dict()`, hardly I will return the property of class from this.